# Coloring chord names in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

How do you color chords in LilyPond?
For example, in the following fragment, how can you print chord names in red?

```
<<
\chords {
  r8 d4 g4 a4 d4 d4:sus4 d4
}
\relative { 
  \time 2/4 \key d \major
  \partial 8
   fis16 e16 fis8 d8 d8
   e16 fis16 e8. d16  d4
  \times 2/3 {g8 fis8 e8} fis4 \bar "|"
}
>>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `\chords` block, include `\override ChordName.color = #red`. For instance:

```
\chords {
  \override ChordName.color = #red
  r8 d4 g4 a4 d4 d4:sus4 d4
}
```

You may want to change some other issues in your code, like changing `\key d` to `\key d \major`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed some other issues, as you suggested.